# Python equivalent of R's save()?

Tags: python, r

In R I can save multiple objects to harddrive using:

```
a = 3; b = "c", c = 2
save(a, b, filename = "filename.R")
```

I can then use `load("filename.R")` to get all objects back in workspace. Is there an equaivalent for Python?

I know I can use

```
import pickle
a = 3; b = "c", c = 2
with open("filename.pkl", 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump([a,b], f)
```

and load it back as:

```
with open("filename.pkl", 'rb') as f:
    a,b = pickle.load(f)
```

but this requires that I know what is inside `filename.pkl` in order to do the assignment `a,b = pickle.load(f)`. Is there another way of doing it that is closer to what I did in R? If not, is there a reason for this that I currently fail to see?

--
edit: I don't agree that the linked question discusses the same issue. I am not asking for all variables, only specific ones. Might well be that there is no way to dump all variables (maybe since some variables in the global env cannot be exported or whatnot...) but still possible to export some.

Comment: Python doesn't really have a concept of "workspace" at all, though I suppose you could futz with `globals()` if you wanted to do something similar-ish.

Comment: if you do just `a = pick.load(f)`, then you get a list `[3, 'c']` which gives you both objects without the variable names. It's a start ... do you *need* the variable names?

Comment: Instead of saving `[a,b]`, you can of course save `dict(a=a, b=b)`, which gives you the names. Reassign them to `globals()`, and you have them back.

Comment: You do not want to save all the variables, only the ones you are interested in. However in R you are saving all the variables (aren't you?) so actually that is the closest thing to what you are doing in R in my opinion. For me a workspace is given by all the varriables, instances, functions and so on. So is it ok or not for you to save all the variables?

Comment: edited the question to make it not save **all** variables